# Execute tests thru API not showing up in test execution?

Tags: api, code-coverage, tooling-api, test-automation

So I wrote a C# program that uses the Salesforce Tooling WSDL to call `RunTestsRequest` . I got that working the only problem I have is the the test results only show up in Apex Test Results and not Apex Test Execution. How can I get tests to run in Apex Test Execution via API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of running Apex tests in Salesforce:

1. Synchronously
2. Asynchronously

The `runTests()` method in the Tooling API is synchronous. It will run the tests while you wait and then return the results.

This differs from `runTestsAsynchronous()`, which unsurprisingly runs the tests asynchronously.  In this case you need to poll for the test outcomes.

The other big difference is that only the asynchronous version will result in the `ApexTestResult` and associated records. It is these records that drive the **Apex Test Execution** in the Salesforce UI.

So, short answer, try switching to running the test async if you want to do things like check the resulting code coverage.

Comment: Thank you for the response I'll give it a shot when I get back to Work on Monday.

Comment: Yep that worked!